# Can each list element navigate to a new view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I am new to SwiftUI and I am trying to create a list featuring each module taken at a university degree. I would like (when clicked on) each module to navigate to a separate, new, view. This is what I hope to achieve:

HomePage -> ListPage ->  each respective module page.

`NavigationLink` only seemed to have one possible destination for all list elements. Is there any way of doing this? Thank you in advance.
This is my current code:

```
struct ListView: View {
    var modules: [Module] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        List(modules) { module in
            NavigationLink(destination: QuizView()) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(module.name)
                Text("\(module.questions) questions")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.subheadline)

            }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Modules"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try returning a specific `View` based on some value (eg. `module.name`):

```
var modules: [Module] = []
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(modules) { module in
            NavigationLink(destination: moduleView(name: module.name)) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("\(module.id)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Modules"))
    }
}
```

```
@ViewBuilder
func moduleView(name: String) -> some View {
    switch name {
    case "module 1":
        View1()
    case "module 2":
        View2()
    default:
        View3()
    }
}
```

Comment: at the line "func moduleView(name: String) -> some View {" I get the error "Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types"

Comment: Did you replace `View1()`, `View2()` with your Views?

Comment: Yes I did: code:        func moduleView(name: String) -> some View {
    switch name {
    case "Organic Chemistry 1":
        return Organic1Quiz()
        
    case "Organic Chemistry 2":
        return Organic2Quiz()
     
    case "Physical Chemistry 1":
        return Physical1Quiz()
        
    case "Inorganic Chemistry 1":
        return Inorganic1Quiz()
        
    case "General Chemistry":
        return GeneralChemistryQuiz()
        
    case "Mathematics for Chemists":
        return MathematicsForChemistsQuiz()
    default:
        return HomeView()
    }
}

Comment: I updated my answer. Now you can return whatever you want: `Button`, `Text`... (as long as it conforms to `View`).